# jQuery - Search string for a value and remove the entire entry up to the li tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got this block of code, which is a `string` because of how ACF works:

```
<div class="acf-fc-popup"><ul><li><a href="#" data-layout="two_column_layout" data-min="0" data-max="0">Two Column Layout</a></li><li><a href="#" data-layout="full_width_content" data-min="" data-max="">Full Width Content</a></li><li><a href="#" data-layout="full_width_image" data-min="" data-max="">Full Width Image</a></li><li><a href="#" data-layout="full_width_video" data-min="" data-max="">Full Width Video</a></li><li><a href="#" data-layout="icons_with_heading" data-min="" data-max="">Icons with Heading</a></li><li><a href="#" data-layout="full_width_image_stretched_with_heading" data-min="" data-max="">Full Width Image (Stretched) with Heading</a></li><li><a href="#" data-layout="instafeed" data-min="" data-max="">Instagram Feed</a></li><li><a href="#" data-layout="content_blocks" data-min="" data-max="">Content Blocks</a></li><li><a href="#" data-layout="gallery" data-min="" data-max="">Gallery</a></li><li><a href="#" data-layout="logo_slider" data-min="" data-max="">Logo Slider</a></li><li><a href="#" data-layout="testimonials" data-min="" data-max="">Testimonials</a></li><li><a href="#" data-layout="call_to_action" data-min="" data-max="">Call to Action</a></li><li><a href="#" data-layout="twitter" data-min="" data-max="">Twitter</a></li><li><a href="#" data-layout="latest_news_slider" data-min="" data-max="">Latest News Slider</a></li><li><a href="#" data-layout="contact_form" data-min="" data-max="">Contact Form</a></li><li><a href="#" data-layout="separator" data-min="" data-max="">Separator</a></li><li><a href="#" data-layout="projects_slider" data-min="" data-max="">Projects Slider</a></li><li><a href="#" data-layout="map" data-min="" data-max="">Full Width Map</a></li><li><a href="#" data-layout="before_after_image" data-min="" data-max="">Before/After Image</a></li><li><a href="#" data-layout="accordion_section" data-min="" data-max="">Accordion Section</a></li></ul></div>
```

What I need to be able to do is look for a value in the `data-layout` attribute inside that large string and remove that, and the wrapping li tags, so for example:

Say I have the value `two_column_layout`, I would want to completely remove `<li><a href="#" data-layout="two_column_layout" data-min="0" data-max="0">Two Column Layout</a></li>`

I have tried this:

```
$(".tmpl-popup:contains('full_width_content')").html(function(_, html) {
   console.log(html.replace(/(full_width_content)/g, '<span class="smallcaps">$1</span>'));
});
```

Which allows me to replace `full_width_content` with the spans, but I can't work out how to extend the match to include the wrapping `li` and essentially replace it with nothing.

Comment: Why are you trying to operate on a string value? Get this parsed as HTML, then you can easily select and remove _elements_ using jQuery methods.

Comment: You shouldn't use a regex for this, but, in case you have to... `/(<li>.*full_width_content.*?<\/li>)/` that should do the trick. The `?` char make the expression to match as less characters as possible

Comment: @Ander That won't work if there is more then one element. Here is an example: https://regex101.com/r/fwcS7q/1

Comment: @CBroe because this is what ACF spits out, this isn't my code

Comment: What does it matter what “spits this out”? To get HTML code parsed as HTML, what does it matter where that code originally came from?

Comment: @Titus You are right, also won't work if the first `li` occurrence it's not the first `li` element. I shouldn't use regex :(

Comment: @CBroe I may be misunderstanding but this string is what ACF is putting inside a script block to populate a list on click, I need to modify what's inside that script block on the fly. I'm not at my desk so i'll give all these a go in a bit :)

Comment: Can’t you do it directly after it has been inserted into the list then? If you can hook into that (or add a second click handler, that then gets invoked after the existing one has updated the list), then you can operate on the resulting DOM structure directly, using jQuery selectors to easily find the element, go up to the parent, and then remove that.

Comment: @CBroe good shout!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a jQuery object, then it can be manipulated via using various apis

```js
var tmpl = '<div class="acf-fc-popup"><ul><li><a href="#" data-layout="two_column_layout" data-min="0" data-max="0">Two Column Layout</a></li><li><a href="#" data-layout="full_width_content" data-min="" data-max="">Full Width Content</a></li><li><a href="#" data-layout="full_width_image" data-min="" data-max="">Full Width Image</a></li><li><a href="#" data-layout="full_width_video" data-min="" data-max="">Full Width Video</a></li><li><a href="#" data-layout="icons_with_heading" data-min="" data-max="">Icons with Heading</a></li><li><a href="#" data-layout="full_width_image_stretched_with_heading" data-min="" data-max="">Full Width Image (Stretched) with Heading</a></li><li><a href="#" data-layout="instafeed" data-min="" data-max="">Instagram Feed</a></li><li><a href="#" data-layout="content_blocks" data-min="" data-max="">Content Blocks</a></li><li><a href="#" data-layout="gallery" data-min="" data-max="">Gallery</a></li><li><a href="#" data-layout="logo_slider" data-min="" data-max="">Logo Slider</a></li><li><a href="#" data-layout="testimonials" data-min="" data-max="">Testimonials</a></li><li><a href="#" data-layout="call_to_action" data-min="" data-max="">Call to Action</a></li><li><a href="#" data-layout="twitter" data-min="" data-max="">Twitter</a></li><li><a href="#" data-layout="latest_news_slider" data-min="" data-max="">Latest News Slider</a></li><li><a href="#" data-layout="contact_form" data-min="" data-max="">Contact Form</a></li><li><a href="#" data-layout="separator" data-min="" data-max="">Separator</a></li><li><a href="#" data-layout="projects_slider" data-min="" data-max="">Projects Slider</a></li><li><a href="#" data-layout="map" data-min="" data-max="">Full Width Map</a></li><li><a href="#" data-layout="before_after_image" data-min="" data-max="">Before/After Image</a></li><li><a href="#" data-layout="accordion_section" data-min="" data-max="">Accordion Section</a></li></ul></div>';

//Create jQuery object
var tmplDiv = $('<div>', {html : tmpl});

//Target element and remove it
tmplDiv.find('a[data-layout="two_column_layout"]').closest('li').remove();

//Update varible
tmpl = tmplDiv.html();

//For debuuging
console.log(tmpl);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: My Answer: `$('<div />').html(html).find('a[data-layout="two_column_layout"]').each(function() {
  $(this).closest('li').remove();
}).end().html();` Convers the case when there are multiple elements with that property.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use regex for something like this.
You can simply create a DOM element and process it.
Here is an example:

```js
var str = `<div class="acf-fc-popup"><ul><li><a href="#" data-layout="two_column_layout" data-min="0" data-max="0">Two Column Layout</a></li><li><a href="#" data-layout="full_width_content" data-min="" data-max="">Full Width Content</a></li><li><a href="#" data-layout="full_width_image" data-min="" data-max="">Full Width Image</a></li><li><a href="#" data-layout="full_width_video" data-min="" data-max="">Full Width Video</a></li><li><a href="#" data-layout="icons_with_heading" data-min="" data-max="">Icons with Heading</a></li><li><a href="#" data-layout="full_width_image_stretched_with_heading" data-min="" data-max="">Full Width Image (Stretched) with Heading</a></li><li><a href="#" data-layout="instafeed" data-min="" data-max="">Instagram Feed</a></li><li><a href="#" data-layout="content_blocks" data-min="" data-max="">Content Blocks</a></li><li><a href="#" data-layout="gallery" data-min="" data-max="">Gallery</a></li><li><a href="#" data-layout="logo_slider" data-min="" data-max="">Logo Slider</a></li><li><a href="#" data-layout="testimonials" data-min="" data-max="">Testimonials</a></li><li><a href="#" data-layout="call_to_action" data-min="" data-max="">Call to Action</a></li><li><a href="#" data-layout="twitter" data-min="" data-max="">Twitter</a></li><li><a href="#" data-layout="latest_news_slider" data-min="" data-max="">Latest News Slider</a></li><li><a href="#" data-layout="contact_form" data-min="" data-max="">Contact Form</a></li><li><a href="#" data-layout="separator" data-min="" data-max="">Separator</a></li><li><a href="#" data-layout="projects_slider" data-min="" data-max="">Projects Slider</a></li><li><a href="#" data-layout="map" data-min="" data-max="">Full Width Map</a></li><li><a href="#" data-layout="before_after_image" data-min="" data-max="">Before/After Image</a></li><li><a href="#" data-layout="accordion_section" data-min="" data-max="">Accordion Section</a></li></ul></div>`;
var elm = $(str);
elm.find("li:has([data-layout=full_width_content])").remove();
$("body").append(elm);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```